# How to rate limit when dealing with databases in Node?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get data from an existing mongo database, and for each document I get, I need to make 2 requests to two different services, github and twitter.

The code works if I put a limit in my cursor, but it stops working when I increase, or remove the limit. I think it is because I'm making too many concurrent requests to either github or twitter or both. I get the message

```
{ [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }
```

I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
col.find({}).limit(100).forEach(function (doc) {
    var options = {};

    var params = {};

    request(options, function (err, response, body) {
          request (options, function (err, response, body){
             // Stuff
          });
        });
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    db.close();
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically starting 100 (or the # of documents that your query results in) HTTP requests in parallel.

The very useful [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) module has a function [`eachLimit`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachLimit) to limit the number of concurrent (running in parallel) asynchronous tasks. In your case, you could leverage it like so:

```
var async = require('async');

col.find({}).limit(100).toArray(function(err, docs) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  // Limit the # of concurrent HTTP requests to 2(-ish).
  async.eachLimit(docs, 2, function(doc, asyncdone) {
    request(options, function (err, response, body) {
      if (err) return asyncdone(err);
      request (options, function (err, response, body){
        if (err) return asyncdone(err);
        // Stuff
        return asyncdone();
      });
    });
  }, function(err) {
    // If we get here, we're done.
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    db.close();
  });
});
```

Be aware that `.toArray()` reads all the query results into memory first (but your `.forEach()` does that as well I think).

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work for all the items. I could only upload about 50 items when I passed 2 as the number of iterators for async.eachLimit. It increased to like 400 when I passed 100.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: NVM I fixed it. I forgot an asyncdone. Thanks for the help man

Answer (score 0):

Should be caused by too many request calls, you can use the async library to do request limit.

mapLimit(arr, limit, iterator, [callback])

it's very easy and trivial to use.